# Help identifying this MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, identification, powermosfet

Trying to figure out what this is, and suitable replacements.  Markings are "1 Wt 77" Cannot seem to find anything.

[image]

**Edit**: I removed and sized it today, looks like 2.04 mm square package, exactly like the one on the below spec sheet... but not that part. Still cannot find those markings...

[image: SiA936EDJ (not a 1Wt)]

Comment: Hmm, 1Wt = SOT-323 Philips (NXP) BF822W NPN transistor.  Is that a SOT-6 package?

Comment: Hi thank you!  it's smaller than the SOT-6 package size... from what I can tell it's closer to this package size: 6-WDFN

Comment: It was 6 pins and I believe is a dual fet chip... not sure if its dual N, dual P or N and P though...

Comment: Hmm, could it be a [SOT-666](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMDT290UNE.pdf) package? May have to measure it.

Answer (score -1):

I removed  and sized it today, looks like 2.04 mm square package that looks exactly like the one on the attached spec sheet... but not the same...cannot find those markings...[image][image]